# How can I build a setup in C# with SQL Server included

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, installation

I created an application using Visual Studio 2010 using SQL Server 2008. How can I build a setup file?

Is it any need of installing SQL Server on another PC to execute my application?

Comment: here is an example tu make setup with database: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/353e10d3-b46e-4234-927d-c2c17d750546/want-to-deploy-my-c-application-with-sql-data-base?forum=vbinterop

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1:  How can I build a setup file?

If you want to build a setup file you need to create a project of `Enable InstallShield Limited Version` from `Setup and Deployment` category (in Visual Studio 2012 IDE)

Follow the steps from this link:

[How to create Setup file](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/)

> Question 2:  is it any need of installing SQL Server on another PC to execute my application?

If you are maintaining any server machine for maintaining your database then you do not need to install SQL Server on client PC's as you can always refer to the `DB-Server` machine by just providing DB-Server hostname/IP address in the `ConnectionString` as below:

```
String connectionString="Data Source=MyDBServerHostName;Initial Catalog=myDBName;UID=myUserID;password=myPassword;Integrated Security=True;"
```

If you don't have any server to maintain database, then you need to install SQL Server on client PC.

Comment: @user3234578 Adding an alternative, you could always build your application on a [file based database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx)